# Visualforce Pass controller method with parameter value

Tags: apex, visualforce

In my controller I have the following method

```
public pagereference goToMaster(string k){
    pagereference redirect = new PageReference('/apex/bridgeToContact?num='+k);
    return redirect;
}
```

I need to pass that method into a table that has one hyperlink per line, and insert the string value eachTrns.recipientWalletID into that method [that value is the cell on its left] when the user click, I am not sure about the syntax, could you please help me.

```
<td><apex:outputLabel value="{!eachTrns.recipientWalletID}"/></td>
<td><apex:commandLink onclick="{!goToMaster({!eachTrns.recipientWalletID})} value="Recipient"/></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need `Apex` for this functionality. Just use `URLFOR`:

```
<apex:commandLink value="Recipient" 
    action="{!URLFOR($Page.BridgeToContact, null, [num=eachTrns.recipientWalletID])}"/>
```

Comment: Wow. Extra credit for using dynamic [] notation!